# WSO2 api manager - How to manage application key and secret by multiple developers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using wso2 apim 2.0

When subscribing to an API, we are assigned a Client ID/Secret which is used to generate the tokens. However, the Client ID is tied to individuals (i.e. each developer on my team is assigned their own Client IDs for the same Aplication). Is there a way for multiple developers to manage application key/secret to access these API's so that they aren't tied to individuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [application sharing feature](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Sharing+Applications+and+Subscriptions) among users of an organization.